# tcsh map complete-word-fwd

Tags: unix, tcsh

i would like to create the following behavior:
right now, when I'm pressing 'TAB' in tcsh it autocompletes the word, if it has ambiguity it gives me a list of possible options and does nothing.

At this point, i would like tcsh to create a list of all options and try to autocomplete the first option, and if i will press UP button i want it to give me the next option.

I did some research and i found that it called "complete-word-fwd"
the problems are:

1. After mapping up key to "complete-word-fwd" ,it disables it's previous behavior - "up-history" , i don't want that. i want it to become "complete-word-fwd" only after tcsh fail to autocomplete due to ambiguity and not to disable UP key from being "up-history" always.
2. mapping UP key to complete-word-fwd is not enough. I want it to autocomplete to the first option (if it has ambiguity) and only then i want to press the up key to scroll between options. right now mapping UP key to "complete-word-fwd" completes only after pressing up key and not automatically.

can anyone please help me? Thanks!